# Dynamic sum based on a condition

Tags: r

```
df <-data.frame(
  part = c('A','B','c'),
  start_date = c('2018-12-01','2018-12-06','2018-12-08'),
  end_date = c('2018-12-05','2018-12-07','2018-12-11'),
  X2018.12.01 = c(2,3,4),
  X2018.12.02 = c(5,6,0),
  X2018.12.03 = c(0,3,0),
  X2018.12.04 = c(5,9,1),
  X2018.12.05 = c(1,2,3),
  X2018.12.06 = c(2,3,4),
  X2018.12.07 = c(1,1,1),
  X2018.12.08 = c(6,6,6),
  X2018.12.09 = c(8,7,6),
  X2018.12.10 = c(0,1,1),
  X2018.12.11 = c(1,2,3))

df1 <- setNames(df, c("part","start_date","end_date","2018-12-01",
"2018-12-02","2018-12-03","2018-12-04","2018-12-05","2018-12-06","2018- 
12-07","2018-12-08","2018-12-09","2018-12-10","2018-12-11"))
```

Now I want create a column in df1 which will do sum for individual parts based on its start_date & end_date

- part A : which should sum from 2018-12-01 to 2018-12-05 which is sum of 2,5,0,5,1 i.e 13,
- part B, which should sum from 2018-12-06 to 2018-12-07 which is 3+1=4
- part c, should sum from 2018-12-08 to 2018-12-11 which is 6+6+1+3= 16

I hope I able to explain my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  gather(date, value, -c(part:end_date)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(start_date:date), lubridate::ymd) %>%
  filter(date >= start_date,
         date <= end_date) %>%
  count(part, wt = value)

## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  part      n
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 A        13
#2 B         4
#3 c        16
```

First, I gather the columns into long form, then convert to dates, filter to only include values within the specified range for each part, and finally sum.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach,

```
sapply(split(df1, seq(nrow(df1))), function(i) 
               rowSums(i[names(i) %in% as.character(seq.Date(as.Date(i$start_date[1]), 
                                                                     i$end_date[1], 
                                                                      by = 'days'))]))
#1.1 2.2 3.3 
#13   4  16
```